# AngularJS how to toggle only one button at a time

Tags: angularjs

My code:

```
<div class="column padding-right-8">
  <button class="btn btn-block btn-long"
          ng-click="swapsCtrl.filters.showLongs = !swapsCtrl.filters.showLongs; swapsCtrl.applyFilters()"
          ng-class="{ 'btn-disabled': !swapsCtrl.filters.showLongs }">Long</button>
</div>
<div class="column padding-left-8">
  <button class="btn btn-block btn-short"
          ng-click="swapsCtrl.filters.showShorts = !swapsCtrl.filters.showShorts; swapsCtrl.applyFilters()"
          ng-class="{ 'btn-disabled': !swapsCtrl.filters.showShorts }">Short</button>
</div>
```

The above code works great, but it allows the users to select both buttons.  My expected behavior:

If .btn-long is selected, then .btn-short gets the class .btn-disabled.
If .btn-short is selected, then .btn-long gets the class .btn-disabled.

It should not be possible for both of the buttons to have the class .btn-disabled nor should it be possible for both buttons to not have the class .btn-disabled.

Comment: you are using two different booleans, therefore you have two separate buttons.   If you don't want them independent, then you either need to use a single boolean, or you need to toggle both booleans on button press.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is what you want, but for *description*, in this sample i try to use simple model we used a `scope.long` to get switch between two buttons, if `long=true` so short button is `disabled` else long button is `disabled`.

```js
var app = angular.module("app", []);
app.controller("ctrl", function($scope){
  $scope.long = null;
  $scope.effect = function(type){
    $scope.long = type ? false : true
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
    <button ng-click="effect(true)" ng-class="{'btn-disabled': long}">long</button>
    <button ng-click="effect(false)" ng-class="{'btn-disabled': !long}">short</button>
    
    
    {{long ? 'long has disable class':'short has disable class'}}
</div>
```